# MySQL Workbench 5.2 edition - Unable to establish the connection

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, mysql-workbench

I have installed MySQL (mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.37-win32.msi ) which is a Windows Installation Workbench.

Couple of times, I have done re-installation on my computer. Now, I am not able to establish the connection.

Following error message is thrown, while i try to connect to the database from Workbench

1. Check that mysql is running on server 127.0.0.1
2. Check that mysql is running on port 3306 ( note : 3306 is the default, but this can be changed )
3. Check the root has rights to connect to 127.0.0.1 from your address (mysql rights define what clients can connect  to the server and from which machines)
4. Make sure you are both  providing a password if needed and using the correct password for 127.0.0.1 connecting from the host address you’re connecting from

Comment: Are you able to connect to server using any other MySQL client?

Comment: I have uninstalled completely and re-installed the MySQL. Still i am facing the same issue. But, I tried installing on different machine, which worked very well !!

Answer (score 1):

I hope your problem might have been already resolved. 
However, I recently had a similar experience and I had to do following to resolve it.
1. Launch MySQL Workbench (Mine was 5.2.36 CE Revision 8542)
2. Double click on a server instance to manage the server instance
3. Goto Users and Privileges 
4. Select root or other user you wish to check from the list in "Server Access Management" tab
5. Change the "Limit connectivity to hosts matching:" to IP that you are using to connect OR just change it to "%" to remove the IP restriction.<6>
6. In my case I had to change it to "%" to make it work.

Hope this will be helpful to someone, someday!
Cheers
Manish.